# Loud crackle noise coming from caps / num lock keys when pressed rapidly

Tags: sound, keyboard, pulseaudio

Ubuntu Version 22.04.2 LTS

Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

Audio from all other sources plays perfectly. When pressing num / caps lock normally, a beeping sound plays normally. When pressing the key rapidly such that the key is being pressed while the sound is already playing, a loud crackling noise happens. The noise seems different depending on how soon the key is pressed after it is pressed for the first time.

This ONLY happens when no other audio source is playing. For example, with a youtube video playing with audio on, pressing the caps / num lock keys at any speed does not cause the noise, and the beeps overlap as you would expect.